# What could be the cause of invalidation of "sys" views?

Tags: oracle, sysdba

I had never experience anything like this but one of the scripts containing

```
select count(*) from user_tables where table_name = 'XXX';
```

started to throw

> PL/SQL: ORA-04063: view "SYS.USER_TABLES" has errors

I use visual tool to look into it - and here it is

[image]

And I see many views are invalidated. What is the possible cause for this? I've never seen `sys.views` invalid.

What I did is ran this to create `alter` scripts

```
select 'alter view SYS.' || object_name || ' compile;' from user_objects where object_type = 'VIEW' and  status = 'INVALID';
```

Created 707 rows. Ran them, still 202 remains problematic. Run again, still 202.

And here is error sample

```
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-04063: view "SYS.DBA_OBJECT_TABLES" has errors
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

**Addition Info**

I started to look into `user_table` definitions. And I tested tables in the `FROM`.

Finding - `select * from sys.deferred_stg$` - table does not exist

Comment: Does `select * from dba_errors where owner = 'SYS' and name = 'USER_TABLES'` return anything interesting?

Comment: @mustaccio it has this `"ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"`

Comment: @mustaccio for the DBA_TABLES --> `"ORA-04063: view "SYS.DBA_TABLES" has errors"`

Comment: the tables are corrupted, if a repair will help, can be a try,. the smart information gathers data directly from the harddrive and tells you if it encounteras defects so you should try to see if the counts are huge and replace the hardware

Comment: @nbk This is oracle on windows hosted in AWS. I don't think this hard-drive related. What do you think?

Comment: even those can be corrupted, but aws has some kind of overview of that. And yes i believe that it is the image that is corrupted. Backups ?

Comment: @nbk no. This is qa/test server. It is easier to re-install the whole thing.  But someone does something wrong and this will happen again

Comment: Reinstall it include an audit and seewqhat happens

Comment: This sort if thing rarely happens spontaneously. I suspect someone with the DBA role has been messing around with that database. Best is to rebuild from scratch, then change the SYS password,, revoke the DBA role from everyone but the DBA. Prevent passwordless access from anyone except the DBA.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind you're totally correct.